# Cannot find matching method - JIRA/Groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

I am trying to calculate the amount of time an issue spent in a status.  But experiencing some errors. The script below goes into the scripted field. Below is my script:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def changeHistoryManager = ComponentAccessor.changeHistoryManager
def currentStatusName = issue?.status?.name

def rt = [0L]
changeHistoryManager.getChangeItemsForField (issue, "status").reverse().each {item ->

    def timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - item.created.getTime()
    if (item.fromString == currentStatusName) {
        rt = -timeDiff
    }
    if (item.toString == currentStatusName){
        rt = timeDiff
    }
}
return (Math.round(rt.sum() / 3600000)) as Double
```

The error is in the last line of the script(the return statement).
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The errors I get are:

> Static type checking - Cannot find matching java.lang.Object#sum() and Cannot find matching method java.lang.Match#round(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `rt` to a Long in your two `if` blocks.  (Just a long, not an array of longs.)  Consequently there is no `.sum()` method available.

You could use

```
rt << -timeDiff
// or
rt << timeDiff
```

to add your timeDiffs to the array rather than redefining it.

You also could just initialize rt as 0 and then use `rt += timeDiff` or `rt -= timeDiff` if you prefer.  It doesn't look like you really need that to exist as an array at all.

Example that may work for you:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

def changeHistoryManager = ComponentAccessor.changeHistoryManager
def currentStatusName = issue?.status?.name

def rt = 0L
changeHistoryManager.getChangeItemsForField (issue, "status").reverse().each {item ->

    def timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - item.created.getTime()
    if (item.fromString == currentStatusName) {
        rt -= timeDiff
    }
    if (item.toString == currentStatusName){
        rt += timeDiff
    }
}
return rt / 3600000
// this could still be Math.round(rt/3600000) as Double if you need that; not sure what you're trying to do with the actual result
```

Comment: What can I use instead of .sum ?